# checkout page is moving up and down

Tags: checkout

please visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-jaggu-keychain.html) click on "**Buy Now**" Button,

than you will be in cart page, than at the end you can see "**Proceed to checkout**" button, once you click that

you can see "checkout" page. try to scroll up & scroll down using mouse .

It showing strange behaviour like fastly going up and down continously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in you `css`

```
.checkout-onepage-index .main-container .container_24 {
    padding-top: 37px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: i added your code in theme.css, but it did't worked.

Comment: Try to increase height i gave sample only also clear cache & Session

Comment: Add this also  margin-bottom: 50px;